¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el codigo compare el primer caracter del String a la letra "P" y que ignore si es mayúscula o minúscula?
¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el codigo compare el primer caracter del String a la letra "P" y que ignore si es mayúscula o minúscula? Ya lo intenté de muchas maneras pero todavía me aparece error justamente en la línea donde hago la comparación:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class primos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ingresar= new Scanner(System.in);
        String comparar="P";

            System.out.println("Si quiere saber si un número es primo ingresarlo con el prefijo P en caso quiera saber su factorial colocar el sufijo !");
            String num = ingresar.nextLine();
            if(num.charAt(0) == "P".equalsIgnoreCase(num)){
                int num2 = Integer.parseInt(num);
                if(num2%2==0){
                    System.out.println("El número no es primo");
                }  else {System.out.println("El número es primo");}
            }
    }
}


Referirse a java como lenguaje de bajo nivel me parece un poco excesivo, siendo uno de los lenguajes que más abstrae al programador de la lógica de bajo nivel :)

ay perdón jaja ya sé para la próxima

Con equalsIgnoreCase comparas un String. A ti te interesa comparar un caracter. Puedes hacer así:
if (num.charAt(0) == "P" || num.charAt(0) == "p")

O así:
if (num.toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'P')


gracias mateoo!

¡Hola! Para comparar el primer carácter del String num con la letra "P" y permitir que la comparación ignore si es mayúscula o minúscula, puedes convertir ambos caracteres a minúscula (o mayúscula) antes de hacer la comparación de esta manera:
if (num.charAt(0) == 'p' || num.charAt(0) == 'P')

Al usar charAt(0), estás accediendo al primer carácter del String num. Luego, estás comparando si ese carácter es igual a 'p' o 'P', ignorando así si es mayúscula o minúscula. No es necesario comparar con la cadena "P" ya que estás comparando con un solo carácter.
Por lo que aquí te muestro el código completo con esta modificación:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class primos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ingresar = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Si quiere saber si un número es primo ingresarlo con el prefijo P en caso quiera saber su factorial colocar el sufijo !");
        String num = ingresar.nextLine();

        if (num.charAt(0) == 'p' || num.charAt(0) == 'P') {
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(num.substring(1)); // Ignorar el primer carácter
            if (num2 % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("El número no es primo");
            } else {
                System.out.println("El número es primo");
            }
        }
    }
}

He añadido, de igual forma, num.substring(1) dentro de parseInt() para convertir la parte del String después del primer carácter a un entero. De esta manera, puedes obtener el número que quieres evaluar para ser primo.
Espero que esta solución te sea de utilidad. :')

Graciasss, me sirvió de mucho!
